# Isometric Immersion and the Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry

I was checking the proof of Hilbert's theorem in do Carmo's book and got stuck in the following proposition:

*If $\psi: S\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is an isometric immersion of an abstract surface $S$ with constant and negative Gaussian curvature, then $\phi = \psi\circ\operatorname{exp}_p:S'\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is also an isometric immersion.*

Here the surface $S'$ is just the plane $T_pS$ endowed with the metric induced by the local diffeomorphism $\operatorname{exp}_p:T_pS\to S$.

**The problem I'm having is to show that $\phi$ is an isometry**. 
Note, by using that $\psi$ is an isometry, we have that

\begin{align*}
\langle d\phi_v(u),d\phi_v(w) \rangle &= \langle d\psi_{\operatorname{exp}_pv}d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(u),d\psi_{\operatorname{exp}_pv}d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(w)\rangle \\
&= \langle d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(u),d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(w)\rangle.
\end{align*}

By some lemma in do Carmo's, we have the inequality

$$
\langle d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(u),d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(u)\rangle\geq \langle u,u\rangle.
$$

I wonder if there is any simple proof since the author doesn't even comment it. The same happens in the [Wikipedia page of Hilbert's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry)), first paragraph of the proof section.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the answer is, in fact, simple. Since the metric on $S'$ is the induced one by $\operatorname{exp}_p$, then by the *definition* of induced metric, we have that

$$
\langle ({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(u),d({\operatorname{exp}_p})_v(w)\rangle
= \langle u,w \rangle.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather nontrivial consequence of nonpositive curvature and is a crucial ingredient in the proof of the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem. See Lemma 1 on p. 384 of DoCarmo.